# partial fields in elasticsearch2.2.0 is not working?

Tags: elasticsearch

May i know the details why the partial fields is not working in elasticsearch 2.2.0.I recently upgraded from elasticsearch 1.7.2 to elasticsearch 2.2.0.In older version it is working but after upgration results are not coming and raising an exception.

Pls find error for your reference

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "search_parse_exception",
            "reason": "failed to parse search source. unknown search element [partial_fields]",
            "line": 79,
            "col": 4
         }
      ],
      "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
      "reason": "all shards failed",
      "phase": "query",
      "grouped": true,
      "failed_shards": [
         {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "candidates1",
            "node": "tlFrZ6JKTOWJ6krrkRnhMw",
            "reason": {
               "type": "search_parse_exception",
               "reason": "failed to parse search source. unknown search element [partial_fields]",
               "line": 79,
               "col": 4
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial fields [have been removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/breaking_20_search_changes.html#_partial_fields) in 2.0 and now you should use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-source-filtering.html) instead.

Simply replace `partial_fields` with `_source` and it should work.